# xtext generate struct of my language when I create file .mydsl in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xtext

When I create file with extension .mydsl in eclipse, I need that the created file contains the struct of my language.

For example, the file contains:

```
use "fileName.mydsl" 

globals {

}

run {

}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: what about registering a custom new file wizard to eclipse?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your question.

Comment: eclipse has the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"` to create your own "new my super duper whatever file" wizard. the easiest is to leverage this one instead of finding some callback to hook in.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_wizard_to_the_New,_Import,_or_Export_menu_categories
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html